# Loading responsive header images for multiple devices and multiple px densities

Tags: css, sketch-3

I have 3 different layouts for a design I completed in Sketch. Each design has a header image as can be seen below:

[image]

On different devices, I load a different image to keep the height in check and crop the image. When I export from Sketch I have the following images:

```
dog-header-mobile-1x.png
dog-header-mobile-2x.png
dog-header-mobile-3x.png
dog-header-mobile-4x.png

dog-header-tablet-1x.png
dog-header-tablet-2x.png
dog-header-tablet-3x.png
dog-header-tablet-4x.png

dog-header-desktop-1x.png
dog-header-desktop-2x.png
dog-header-desktop-3x.png
dog-header-desktop-4x.png
```

I'd like to load the 1x, 2x, 3x and 4x images where appropriate. But what's confusing me is I have 3 different images for the 3 devices so do I need to use `srcset` AND `sizes` to achieve this? It seems like a very long-winded way to do this and I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element.

```
<picture>
    <source
        media="(max-width: 740px)"
        srcset="
            dog-header-mobile-1x.png,
            dog-header-mobile-2x.png 2x,
            dog-header-mobile-3x.png 3x,
            dog-header-mobile-4x.png 4x">
    <source
        media="(max-width: 1440px)"
        srcset="
            dog-header-tablet-1x.png,
            dog-header-tablet-2x.png 2x,
            dog-header-tablet-3x.png 3x,
            dog-header-tablet-4x.png 4x">
    <source
        srcset="
            dog-header-desktop-1x.png,
            dog-header-desktop-2x.png 2x,
            dog-header-desktop-3x.png 3x,
            dog-header-desktop-4x.png 4x">

    <img src="dog-header-desktop-1x.png" alt="Dog">
</picture>
```

IE doesn't support it, but will fallback to the default `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried out media queries?
You can define the size when you want to use mobile, tablet or desktop version. There you can also set a different background-image for your header-image.

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Can CSS load images based on pixel density/device?

Comment: Ah, I found `min-resolution` with media queries. Thankfully `autoprefixer` takes care of vendor prefixes. Many thanks. Although this wasn't the solution, it was helpful in helping me find a solution.

Comment: @BugHunterUK you can set media queries for different pixel ratio with "device-pixel-ration", so I guess yes, it should be possible. Maybe the following link can help you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/